# Graphical layers won't load

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-4

My friend has a problem with his BF4 his graphical layers won't load. They stay at the layer where objects and shapes aren't rendered and everything is smooth. You get this a lot when loading into a map but stays for a short time, but this stays with him the whole time and doesn't render to full HD graphics, is there anyway of fixing this?

Comment: Odd, I have this "texture pop-in" at the start of new games somtimes, but I'm playing on PC.

Comment: I get that too on PS4, but it usually goes away within 10 seconds or so if I go prone and wait it out.